# Binding Server Socket

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket

I'm creating simple `ServerSocket` based server in Java with 2 main services (let's say `Service A` and `Service B`).
I'd like to know how can I bind two different methods with two different routes so:

`net.tcp://localhost:5555/service-A` was handled by method `A`
and
`net.tcp://localhost:5555/service-B` was handled by method `B`

I know it's possible in WCF. Can I do this with `ServerSockets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible. ServerSocket will bind to a port and listen to all incoming connections. However you could handle the "routing" after the incoming connection (i.e the return from the `accept` method) by reading the incoming request, parsing it and passing the data to your "services".
From the look of it you want to do "HTTP" like routing, I would suggest that you use some kind of HTTPServer/Service instead of the "raw" `ServerSocket`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Altough I cannot use HTTPServer as you've proposed.
The solution you've suggested is the one that I used. I was wondering if I can achieve this in more simple way.